# What's the process for filling the position left by a moderator that steps down?

Tags: discussion

When a community-elected moderator vacates their position, for whatever reason, what's the process for replacing them?

Do we just wait until the next elections, even if it's 4-6 months away?

Do community moderators help pick up any (potential) slack?

Is there some other process in place for selecting another candidate?

On Beta sites, I believe moderators are usually replaced fairly quickly, with existing moderators and CMs choosing an active member that displays moderator qualities. I can't find information here or on main meta that deals with replacing mods on full stacks, although I'm sure that has to occur frequently enough.

Comment: Can't elections be held at any time? I'm pretty sure "even if it's 4-6 months away" doesn't really work like that. 6-8 weeks maybe :-P

Comment: @rand They're usually held around January or so, and historically haven't had more than one a year here. I haven't surveyed all other stacks to see if it happens whenever. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: Elections are held whenever the mods and CMs decide they want another mod or two. January-February is largely irrelevant, it's just when we've happened to have elections here.

Comment: @Kevin That's consistent with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99512/when-do-moderator-elections-take-place, but doesn't address that you technically decided you needed/wanted another mod already and now are one less than the number you previously wanted

Comment: @CreationEdge While Richard cleared a lot of flags, his absence hasn't caused any strain on the current mods. When we "decide [we] want another mod or two" may be affected by the resignation of a current mod, but at this point we're not hurting for one.

Comment: *"On Beta sites, I believe moderators are usually replaced fairly quickly"* - Uh, may I ask what beta sites you were around on? ;-)

Comment: @Tars Parenting has had moderators replaced very quickly in my experience.

Comment: @Kevin Okay. I'm not specifically talking about Richard, which is why I didn't mention it. That sparked the question, but it was more general. But between you and Mice Elf I have my answer.

Comment: @CreationEdge Actually, when I asked to step down from moderating parenting, it took months to find replacements. I stuck around much longer than I had planned, while dealing with drastically reduced availability, until we could finish the transition.  It's a testament to Karl's dedication that it seemed as quick a transition as it apparently appeared.

Comment: @Beofett I guess I was thinking of when Karl stepped down and was quickly (from a user perspective) replaced by Erica. And historically, it was only about 2 months to replace Torben and cabbey with Karl and balancedmama.

Comment: I know that in our little corner (Workplace.SE), it was when the current mods felt they needed another pair of hands due to the ongoing growth of the community, rather than any particular event or timing.  They got stuck with me :)

Answer (score 11):

> There will be another moderator election in the coming weeks to ensure a full moderator team is here to serve the community going forward.

[So says Ana](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7330), a community manager.

But generally, there are three options (on graduated sites):

1. Election happens earlier than it would otherwise.
2. The results of recent election are recalculated with an increased number of mod positions. [Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296975).
3. Nothing happens, if the remaining mods are still enough for the job.

Comment: Thank you. This addresses not only the current situation, but other scenarios as well, which is what my question is really about.