# When is the next Moderator Election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Having just stumbled across [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7319/why-was-a-moderator-on-our-stack-asked-to-step-down), I'm very curious as to when the next Moderator Election will be held.

Does anyone have any information?

Comment: it's been a while now since that happened, but at least at the time, they were ok with the current workload after the staff change. there's no need for a new mod election unless/until they decide they need a new mod to help out.

Comment: Thanks @phantom42

Comment: Don't we already *have* a new moderator? Who's this AncientSwordRage guy on the mod list? ;-)

Comment: Tempted to throw my hat into the ring

Comment: @Richard :D you've got my vote

Comment: @Daft - There's a [precedent](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/133/a-problematic-yet-popular-user-is-running-for-moderator-how-can-we-make-sure-t) for refusing nominations and [removing nominations](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/825). I'm pretty sure the "powers-that-be" would exercise that privilege to block me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When the current moderator team feels it's necessary, and time permits.

Given the holidays, it'd probably be best to not hold one any sooner than January; whether one is necessary *then* is a decision the current moderator team should make based on their availability and workload.

Comment: Is there a preferred number of Mods for a stack?

Comment: As few as necessary and no fewer.

Comment: Delightfully vague!

Comment: Nicely paraphrased @shog9