# wrong vote score in sidebar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-questions

Looking at the sidebar in [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7319/5184), the post [Stepping down as Moderator](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/stepping-down-as-moderator?lq=1) is listed twice - once in the "linked" section, and once in the "related section". However, the scores displayed on the links are different. As of this moment, the post has 14 upvotes and no downvotes.

Is this just a caching issue? If so, why is only one section cached, but not the other?

[image: wrong scores]

Comment: They're both 14 for me... Maybe a caching issue that is not an issue any more?

Comment: This site might help you; [Should I blame caching?](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the contents of both sidebars are cached. Looking at the current code, the Linked sidebar is cached for 5 minutes, and the Related sidebar is cached for 1 hour.

The entire HTML content of the sidebar is what's cached, not the question IDs or what not. So the scores for the questions won't be updated live.

Comment: It might be "by design" for a developer but for a user it is a bug. I think it should be fixed; eg cache both for one hour.